# Express middleware (with app.use): Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on Express.js middleware that, whenever a .xcss file is requested, compiles that file and returns a .css stylesheet. It *works*, but I nonetheless get the console error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

This isn't a new error to me, but this is the first time I have literally no idea how to solve it. I'm not sure why there are two responses being sent for the .xcss GET request (if that's even what's happening). The res.setHeader before the res.send doesn't do any difference.

All relevant code is below:

**start.js:**

```
const express   = require('express')
const app       = express()
const path      = require('path')
const xcss      = require('../lib/middleware')
const publicDir = path.join(__dirname, 'public')

app.use(xcss())
app.use(express.static(publicDir))

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('index.html')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

**middleware.js:**

```
const path     = require('path')
const compiler = require('./compiler')

module.exports = function(options) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        const relativePath = req.url
        const absolutePath = path.join(options.src, relativePath)
        const fileExtension = path.extname(relativePath)

        if (fileExtension === '.xcss') {
            const css = compiler.compile(absolutePath)
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/css')
            console.log('>>> BEFORE')
            res.send(css) // <----- The offending line.
            console.log('>>> AFTER')
        }

        next()
    }
}
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="css/style.xcss" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
</html>
```

**console.log (with the morgan logger):**

```
::1 - - [13/Sep/2017:08:07:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
>>> BEFORE
>>> AFTER
::1 - - [13/Sep/2017:08:07:16 +0000] "GET /css/style.xcss HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36"
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at SendStream.headersAlreadySent (D:\Node.js\zigrid\node_modules\send\index.js:402:13)
    at SendStream.send (D:\Node.js\zigrid\node_modules\send\index.js:625:10)
    at onstat (D:\Node.js\zigrid\node_modules\send\index.js:737:10)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
```

Comment: `return res.send(css);`

Comment: As @AikonMogwai said you need to RETURN a response in middleware.js Currently you are sending a response and after if statement you are calling next() which will again send response later on.

Comment: Yessss. Thank you all for the help, works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (fileExtension === '.xcss') {
    const css = compiler.compile(absolutePath)
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/css')
    console.log('>>> BEFORE')
    res.send(css) // <----- The offending line.
    console.log('>>> AFTER')
 }

 next() //remove this line
```

i think the problem is related to the fact that you're calling `next()` after you send the http response.
`next()` calls the next middleware in the chain, and if for any reason you write the response stream or the headers after the `send()` this can cause the error.

try to avoid calling `next()` when you enter the if branch or make sure the coming middleware don't set any headers

Comment: So that's how the middleware chain works. This worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (fileExtension === '.xcss') {
    const css = compiler.compile(absolutePath)
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/css')
    console.log('>>> BEFORE')
    res.send(css) // <-----Removet this line and add next(css); 
    console.log('>>> AFTER')
 }
```

Comment: >`res.send(css) // <-----Removet this line and add next(css); 

` Calling `next ` with a parameter will invoke  the error middleware; i dont think that's what OP wants